# Fill column B with column A

Tags: excel, vba

So, I have two columns. Column A has content with <> tags and Column B has content with [].

```
1    <hi>     [hi]
2    hello    bye
3    </hi>    [/hi]
```

Column B has a filter on top and both columns are filtered so that the cells with <> and [] are left out, and then I select all Column A and move it to B (with the little 'plus' sign at the bottom or top of the selection). The ending result would be something like this, when unfiltered:

```
1    <hi>     [hi]
2    hello    hello
3    </hi>    [/hi]
```

So I make a macro for this and it all works alright until it gets to **Selection.FillRight**

```
  Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B:$B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*[*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Range("A1:A25").Select
    Selection.FillRight
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B:$B").AutoFilter Field:=1
End Sub
```

I've tried using this

```
Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

or

```
Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$B$25")
```

instead but it won't work either. Any idea of how to fill all (filtered) content from Column A to Column B? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if my way would be better, but I would likely do something like `For each rcell in rng` `Do check for filter criteria` `If True Then Copy to Offset Cell`

Comment: There is no difference between your first and second set of sample data, I'm having trouble understanding the final result expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in the VBA version of `FillRight`.

Here's an alternative (which avoids that nasty Select / Selection)

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range, cl As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' or a specific sheet
    Set r = ws.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each cl In r
        cl.Offset(0, 1) = cl.Value ' or cl.Formula
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: So if there wasn't a bug, `FillRight` would be the correct tool? I just read the Microsoft Docs and the description didn't seem to fit the requested action. `The contents and formatting of the cell or cells in the leftmost column of a range are copied into the rest of the columns in the range.`

Comment: @Free Seems to fit the OPs requirement to me.   I say bug because it behaves differently in VBA to in Excel (and the macro recorder records pretty much the code the OP posted, but it won't run on a fiilterd list)